# Is there a way to change the digits shown in the variables browser?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

the matlab variables browser in the IDE GUI per default only shows 10 digits. longer variables have their dimension shown.

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]   
[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
<1x11 double>
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
<1x11 double>
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0]
```

is there a way to modify this behavior in matlab 8.1 ?

Comment: I don't find anything in Matlab 2013, even looking in the file matlab.prf (found into Matlab's preference directory). Seems to be internal to Matlab...

Comment: Yair Altman from [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) once got challenged to [change the displaying of bytes to kbytes](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-matlabs-workspace-table/) in the workspace table. Maybe you can challenge him to find a solution for your request. I doubt there is a trivial solution. But it seems to me that for the newest release the [workspace preferences](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html) got extended.

Answer (score 0):

As you may already have guessed from the comments:

**No**, there is no setting that can be changed via regular means to modify this behavior.

Of course everything is possible, but the 'easiest' way would probably require a java hack, like [the one for changing the workspace preferences](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/customizing-matlabs-workspace-table).